# Htaccess not working with two slashes

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I try to make a custom link like:

```
mysite.com/users/test
```

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ index.php?h=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ index.php?h=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

My problem is: with one "/something" is working, the index.php loads correctly but with "/something/test" I'm gettin a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <.

Thankyou.

Comment: It sounds like that error is coming from your `index.php` script and not from apache or the rewrite engine

Comment: When I'm using two slashes the index.php thinks that is in the "first" folder and is not finding the resources. @JonLin

Answer (score 1):

I think the "`\/`" in the following is incorrect.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ index.php?h=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I think that should be:
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)/(.*)$ index.php?h=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]`

One thing to note with your definitions is that there is no `RewriteBase` directive specified and the `index.php` portion would usually be preceded by a leading slash - which leads to:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ /index.php?h=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)/(.*)(/?)$ /index.php?h=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Tested this using the url `https://localhost/something/somethingelse/blahblah/?page=1` which showed the following GET variables:-

```
Array
(
    [h] => something
    [p] => somethingelse/blahblah
    [page] => 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider but still getiing an error when I am using : Localhost/testsite/something/somethingelse. The index.php thinks that is in the something folder and is not finding the resources.